# keep activity going in background when switched to another activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have my main activity going and a button going to a different activity. When I go to the other activity my main activity stops. How would I keep the main activity going?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, you can't do this. What is it you want to achieve? Continual processing needs the use of separate threads, services etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can keep your main Activity running. My way is use a "CHEAT".

Example your main Activity is A, in A we have button btnA. Click this btnA will open activity B.

You create a tab bar with 2 tab contains A and B. After initialize tab bar, call

```
tabHost.getTabWidget.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to hide this tab. So you only see main Activity visible.

When btnA is clicked, only need to switch tabHost to B

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);//1 is index of Activity B
```

This question & answer is similar with your question. You can refer to it.

[Activities and sub activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581606/activities-and-sub-activities/5581986#5581986)

Answer (score 4):

> How would I keep the main activity going?

You wouldn't.

Depending on what it is that you are doing, you might consider moving it to a `Service`.